# "" must have required property 'browserTarget'

Tags: angular

While ng serve getting below error

> Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
> Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.

I have the configuration like below

- Angular CLI: 17.0.8
- Node: 20.9.0
- Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
- OS: win32 x64

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "shipment_tracking": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/shipment_tracking",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "shipment_tracking:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "shipment_tracking:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "shipment_tracking:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "shipment-tracking",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `build-angular` dev dependency seems to be wrong, kindly use the below working example as reference, compare the package.json to yours and change the versions then do an `npm i` hopefully your issue will get resolved!

```
{
  "name": "stackblitz-starters-cgdng5",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "0.14.2",
    "@angular/core": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/forms": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/common": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/router": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/animations": "17.0.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "17.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cgdng5?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=package.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using angular cli 17, but your package.jason shows 16.2.11 on the dev dependencies.

Change

```
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.11",
"@angular/cli": "^17.0.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"typescript": "~5.2.2"
```

TO

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "^17.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"typescript": "~5.2.2"
```

}

and do

```
npm install
```

This should fix your issue. The issue is you are telling angular to use version 16.2.11 for dev build while your angular is version 17.